# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on string in PHP DOM curl

Tags: php, curl, dom

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dom\curldom.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dom\curldom.php on line 22

**giving this error**

```
            <?php

        include('simple_html_dom.php');

        function getCode($url)
        {
            $ch=curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com/');
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $html = file_get_contents($output);
            //return $output;
        }
        $url = 'http://www.amazon.in/Honor-6X-Grey-64GB/dp/B01LWZ14Z2/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1494825701&sr=1-1&keywords=honor+6x';
        $varc = getCode($url);
        $cost = $varc->find('span[id=priceblock_saleprice]');
        // $price ='/<span id="priceblock_saleprice">/';
          //  preg_match_all($price,$varc,$cost);
        echo $cost;

        ?>
```

Comment: function find does not exist. Also this is not a class. YOu cannot access functions like that when its not a php class

Comment: lol...... //return $output; remove comment  on this line

Comment: i already did tthat still not working @BilalAhmed

Comment: find funtion exist on simple_html_dom.php i had include that file @Akintunde

Comment: Give me few minutes.  I'll help

Comment: thank you what i need to do is scrap price of any amazon product using its product link via php

Comment: ??????@Akintunde

Answer (score -1):

is there you creating object anywhere if not  use following code

instead of that         $cost = $varc->find('span[id=priceblock_saleprice]');

use          $cost = find('span[id=priceblock_saleprice]');

Comment: But now in this command $cost = find('span[id=priceblock_saleprice]');
where find function will work?
In above program $varc is extraction code from a page and then in this snippet ( $cost = $varc->find('span[id=priceblock_saleprice]'); ) 
find fucntion finding given span id from varc..